# Looping textbox IDs for retrieving text from textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 50 text boxes starting from TextBox1 till TextBox50. I want to retrieve values from all these 50 text boxes. I tried looping but it failed. I want some code like TextBox(i).Text where i varies from 1 to 50.
The loop should produce the following result.
Response.Write(TextBox1.Text);
Response.Write(TextBox2.Text);
 son on till 
Response.Write(TextBox50.Text);

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `I tried looping but it failed` Please show your code. What do you mean "failed"? Compile error? Runtime exception? Unexpected output? Be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FindControl` which takes a string as parameter, pass it `"TextBox" + i` like:

```
TextBox tb = this.FindControl("TextBox" + i) as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    Response.Write(tb.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop thought them simply as following :

```
string value=""; // store each textbox value in this variable
foreach (Control x in this.Controls) // loop through the controls in the form
{
   if (x is TextBox) // if the program found a textbox in the form
   {
      value = (x as TextBox).Text; // set the value of the textbox number x to the string value
      listBox1.Items.Add(value); // here is a listbox to show the resule
   }
}
```